# Interaction (display, change,...) with my data

Tags: newmips

I have a newmips app (on the Cloud) and I want to interact with my data. The only interaction I found in newMips was a data export to CSV or Excel (for the import I think I should go to the studio).

I need to display my data with the tools I developed on my web site (PHP).

Is there a [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) (or at least a read) in a REST standard (or not)? Or is it possible to know the database connection that will give me access to my data tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newmips natively exposes REST API services on all entities managed.

To use it, you must define a client account (with role / group) in API credential menu of authentification module (use drop-down list on left of the editor to access it).

Documentation of your application API is auto-generated and can also be accessed in authentification module.

Note. There is no other tools yet available (except export features) to retrieve data.

Comment: How nice. Could not find it the doc.

Comment: Go in your generated application through Newmips preview in the Studio.
Select Authentification module in drop-down list.
Click on menu "Settings" (paramètres)
Link to REST API documentation is on top of page.

Comment: Direct access for environment `myenv` and application `myapp` is `https://myenv-myapp.newmips.studio/api_documentation/`

Comment: Found it, finaly!